# how to display blob images

Tags: php, mysql

i am trying to insert & display multiple blob images but because of some mistake its not appearing to the page and multiple images also not getting saved, the code is as follows:
test1.php[inserting the blob images]:

```
$conn  = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "test");

for($i=0; $i<count($_FILES["userfile"]["name"]); $i++){

    $imageName = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_FILES["userfile"]["name"]);
    $imageData = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_FILES["userfile"]["tmp_name"]);
    $imageType = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_FILES["userfile"]["type"]);
    $image     = file_get_contents($imageData);
    $image     = base64_encode($image);
    if($imageName!=''){

        mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO files SET mime = '".$imageName."', data= '".$image."' ");
        $result =   array("insert_res"=>"110");
        echo json_encode($result);

    }else{
        $result =   array("insert_res"=>"111");
        echo json_encode($result);
    }
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Image Upload</title>
    </head>
    <body>
<!--        <form name="" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>" id="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="image" id="image" />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" />-->
             <img src="test_dis.php?id=1" />
        <!--</form>-->

    </body>
</html>
```

test_disp.php[display images from database]:

```
$conn  = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "test");


if(isset($_GET['id'])){
$id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['id']);

$sql       = "SELECT * FROM files WHERE id = '".$id."' ";
$result    = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
While($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
$imageData = $row[data];
}
header("contetnt-type: image/jpg");
echo $imageData;
}
else{
    echo 'error';
}
```

for single image its working fine, but when there are multilple images its not inserting all and also not fetching.
i m getting these all images from an IOS App.
how to solve it ?please hlp
while displaying its coming like this.
[image]

[image]
 after insertion its repeating first image three times but from IOS app i am getting 3 images only, its skipping one image

[image]

Comment: Fix typo: `contetnt-type` should be `content-type`

Comment: while copying the code i made this mistake otherwise its "content" only in the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you are not looping over the `$FILES` array properly. All you need to do is add the `$i` loop counter to the `$FILES....` references

```
$conn  = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "test");

for($i=0; $i<count($_FILES["userfile"]["name"]); $i++){

    $imageName = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_FILES["userfile"]["name"][$i]);
    $imageData = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_FILES["userfile"]["tmp_name"][$i]);
    $imageType = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_FILES["userfile"]["type"][$i]);
    $image     = file_get_contents($imageData);
    $image     = base64_encode($image);
    if($imageName!=''){

        $res = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO files 
                                    SET mime = '$imageName', 
                                        data= '$image'");

        if ( $res === false ) {
            // check insert worked, reply with error 112 if not
            $e = mysqli_error($conn);
            echo json_encode( array(
                                    'insert_res'=>'112'
                                    'insert_error' => $e
                                   )
                            );
        } else {
            echo json_encode(array("insert_res"=>"110"));
        }
    }else{
        $result =   array("insert_res"=>"111");
        echo json_encode($result);
    }
}    
?>
```

You have encoded your original image i.e. `base64_encode()` so you need to reverse this encoding so it becomes an image again.

test_disp.php

```
$conn  = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "test");

if(isset($_GET['id'])){
    $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['id']);

    $sql       = "SELECT * FROM files WHERE id = '$id'";
    $result    = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    if ( $result === false ) {
        // check the query actually worked
        echo mysqli_error($conn);
        exit;
    }
    $row       = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

    header("content-type: image/jpg");
    echo base64_decode($row[data]);             // < added function

} else {
    echo 'error';
}
```

You also dont need a while loop when a query will only return one result row!

Comment: yes that was a mistake i was not decoding it, now its display the image, but at the time of insertion its not uploading multiple images, its repeating 1 receiving images 3 time and then saving second image

Comment: i was trying to insert multiple images on 1 id, but i m not able to insert it, is it possible to insert multiple images in database on a single id? and to fetch them/

Comment: But I assume the `id` in your database table is defined as `auto increment` so 3 images will each have a seperate unique id

Comment: if i have to insert 3 images in one id then wat i can do?

Comment: So you will need another column in that table. For example `group_id` and you will have to give that a number/code that relates to this specific upload set. Then chnage the `test_disp` code to query on that new `group_id`

Comment: okay. i have added database table's after insertion state for your reference, first image its repeating 2 time and at last image its skipping while insertion

Comment: Ahh ok, i see the issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111426/discussion-between-ashish-and-riggsfolly).

Comment: There have a look at the answer again